# Can not return an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

The program below aims to return all the nonzero values in the array A using the array B.

I am new to Java, but experienced with C++.

Would gladly appreciate any feedback !

```
public class first 
{
    static int [] A= { 5, 43, 0, 127, 1, 0 ,0 ,3};

    public static int[] NonZeros( int [] A )
    {

        int [] B= new int [10];
        int k=0;
        for(int i=0;i<=7;i++)
            if(A[i]!=0)
            { 
                B[k]=A[i];
                k++;
            }


        return B;
    }
                        public static void main(String[] args)
                        { 

                            System.out.println(NonZeros(A));
                        }
}
```

Output:

```
 [I@659e0bfd
```

Comment: Use Arrays.toString(NonZeros(A)) to get a String representation of the array.

Comment: Jep. It's like in C++ with the pointer reference thing. Use (like said above) 'toString'.

Comment: @Nico These numbers are neither a pointer or a reference to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(NonZeros(A)));
```

in your `main` method.

Comment: Thanks! After importing java.util.Arrays, this worked like expected.